# 2007 T5 AWD Volvo S40 key won't start the car or unlock the doors

Tags: starting, volvo, keyless-entry

I didn't drive the car for three weeks. When I went to open the car to drive to work my keyless entry fob wouldn't work so I used the actual key to open the door. When I tried to start the car of course it wouldn't turn over, no lights or display popped up either. I took the plastic insert "key" out and tried to use my key but that didn't work either and now I can't even get the key out. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You have a flat battery - use either a charger or a jump-start from another car (there are plenty of questions on here and guides elsewhere as to how to jump start) to charge the battery.